# $f \mapsto f \circ \tau$ is an isometry if and only if $\tau$ is surjective

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact topological spaces and let $\tau : X \longrightarrow Y$ be a continous function. Define $A: f \mapsto f \circ \tau$, for $f \in \mathcal{C}(X)$. Then, $A$ is bounded and $\lVert A \rVert = 1$. Furthermore, $A$ is an isometry if and only if $\tau$ is surjective.

I've tried to prove this, but I'm not sure if this computation is right.
$$\lVert A \rVert = \sup_{f \in B_{\mathcal{C}(X)}} \lVert Af \rVert = \sup_{f \in B_{\mathcal{C}(X)}} \lVert f \circ \tau \rVert = \sup_{f \in B_{\mathcal{C}(X)}} \sup_{y \in B_Y} \lvert f(\tau(y)) \rvert = 1$$
taking $f$ constant. Is this correct?

On the other hand, I'm not sure how to prove the 'furthermore' part. If $\tau$ is surjective, then
$$\lVert Af \rVert = \sup_{y \in B_Y} \lvert f(\tau(y)) \rvert = \sup_{x \in B_X} \lvert f(x) \rvert = \lVert f \rVert$$
Is this correct?

Comment: In the last part I would include the argument of why those equalitties are true. You need to say that the first supremum is attained, then use the surjectivity to show that the second is attained too at a pre-image of where the first is attained.

Comment: The first part is good. Well, maybe include that $\left\|f\circ \tau\right\|\leq 1$ since $f\in B_{C(X)}$. That is why the example $f\equiv 1$ is all it is needed to give you the other inequality $\geq1$.

Comment: Great! Thank you! The fact that the supremum is attained is due to the compactness of the space, because the functions are continuous, right?